# C# object representation of JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON string:

```
{
    "region" : { 
        "center" : {
            "title" : "Center Region"
        },
        "east" : {
            "title" : "East Region - Form"
        }
    },
    "buttons" : {
        "save" : "Save"
    },
    "fields" : {
        "labels" : {
            "firstName" : "First Name",
            "lastName" : "Last Name",
            "chooseLocale" : "Choose Your Locale"
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering whether this (see below) is the correct representation of the JSON string in C#:

```
public class Region 
{
    public Region() { }
}

public class Center : Region
{
    public Center() { }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class East : Region
{
    public East() { }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Buttons
{
    public Buttons() { }
    public string save { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public Fields() { }
}

public class Labels : Fields
{
    public Labels() { }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string chooseLocale { get; set; }
}
```

I need the correct object representation which I can then serialize using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);` in order to produce the JSON string above.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/  works a treat

Comment: In ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2+ you also have ['Paste JSON as classes'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using inheritance?

Your Json describes **has a** relationships, not **is a** relationships

The hierarchy goes:

> **region** *has* center, east
>
> **buttons** *has* save
>
> **fields** *has* labels
>
> labels *has* firstName, lastName, chooseLocale

**Bold** are root

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class Center
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class East
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public Center center { get; set; }
    public East east { get; set; }
}

public class Buttons
{
    public string save { get; set; }
}

public class Labels
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string chooseLocale { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public Labels labels { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Region region { get; set; }
    public Buttons buttons { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i see what you did there

Comment: Try json2csharp.com as Yakyb has specified :) .